# Compiler error probably assiociated with typedef

Tags: c, char, int, typedef, unsigned

For some reason my following program won't compile, I cant really find out why. I put the method between comments so the error isn't located there I guess it might have something to do with the typedef.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef unsigned char uchar;
typedef unsigned int uint;

uchar register(uint);

int main() {
uint data =  819;
/*
printf("%c", register(data));
*/  
}
uchar register(uint data) {
/*
    uchar reg = 0;
    while(data != 0) {
    if(reg&0x80 == 1) {
        reg=reg<<1;
        reg += data&0x1;
        data = data>>0;
        reg = reg ^ 81;
    }
    else {
        reg<<1;
        reg += data&0x1;
        data = data>>0; 
    }
}
return reg;
*/
}
```

Errors:

```
[Note] previous declaration of 'uint' was here
[Error] expected ')' before 'data'
[Error] expected expression before 'register'
```

Comment: `register` is a keyword in C, you can't call a function `register`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
after all the coding errors were corrected, it compiled with no errors.
note that no changes were made to the typedef statements.

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef unsigned char uchar;
typedef unsigned int uint;

uchar Myregister(uint);

int main()
{
    uint data =  819;
    printf("%c", Myregister(data));
    return(0);
}

uchar Myregister(uint data)
{
    uchar reg = 0;
    while(data != 0)
    {
        if( (reg&0x80) == 1)
        {
            reg=reg<<1;
            reg += data&0x1;
            data = data>>1;
            reg =  reg ^ 81;
        }
        else
        {
            reg =  reg<<1;
            reg += data&0x1;
            data = data>>1;
        }
    }
    return reg;
}
```